# What is the Pair ingredient in Toriko?

Tags: toriko

I've read those chapters over and over and I still don't understand what Pair is.

Was it a fruit that was eaten by a monkey and it became its testicles? Was it monkey testicles in the first place that got removed and put in the tree?

Answer (score 1):

Pair is the pair of testicles of a Ballboon.

Monkey King Bambina's Pair is the hardest to get, and also the most delicious because it is fresh off the monkey. The Ballboons hang their Pairs from the Birth Cry Tree as a mating ritual.

Retrieving Pair from the Birth Cry Tree can be accomplished with 2 means: Eating someone of similar power to yourself, or having a Ballboon pluck them off the tree.

Originally, Pair's capture method was much much different, but one of Bambina's ancestors ate the original source of Pair, and this drastically altered its obtaining method